# Furniture design software

Tags: design

What software can be used to furniture design; woodwork, glass and metal (stainless steel and aluminum)?
Desirable features:

- Material cut optimization
- Animation (maybe with physics)
- Export to plans (front, top, isometric. etc.)

I guess there could be specialized (and expensive) software but what about average user/builder/carpenter?

Comment: Have a look at [this comment thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/what-is-an-appropriate-software-for-furniture-design) on [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com). They seem to have some ideas.